# Monitor when a device disconnects my wifi network

Tags: macos, wifi, network-connection

I am working on a simple hobby project that checks when users connect/disconnect from my wifi network.

**What works:**
I have a `Python` script running on Mac OS 10.6 that basically `tail`s the system log `/var/log/system.log`. So, the script just checks for the `MAC Address` of my iPhone and if it finds it, it knows that I've connected.

**What I am trying to do:**
Now, I am trying to find when this iPhone disconnects my wifi network (Although, I don't need to know what networks it ends up joining next). I tried looking at some [NMAP Commands](https://superuser.com/questions/48611/can-i-monitor-who-is-using-my-mac-os-x-internet-sharing) to check for the `DHCP lease file` but haven't been successful yet.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devices typically don't "disconnect" from DHCP - the leases simply expire and that can take hours or weeks depending on the DHCP settings. However, iPhones do respond to pings while on WiFi so you can ping it periodically to find out whether it is still connected.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Simon. Actually, by disconnect I mean when the phone jumps on to another network (wifi OR 3g) BEFORE it's DHCP license expired. Do we get a "callback" or a "log" somewhere about this?

Comment: No. That's why I said the only way is to actively check that e.g. with ping.

Comment: Okay, if someone else or myself find a solution for this, I will update this thread.